# no-www to www without using https

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

I have ssl certificate but not using it. This code should force to http and www . It works in this case scenario

http://mysite dot com >> http://www.mysite dot com
https://www mysite dot com >> http://www.mysite dot com

but when I type

https://mysite dot com >> I get Privacy error and red mark as connection not private

> Your connection is not private
>
> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from

This is my code

```
#Force WWW + SSL
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com
#RewriteRule (.*) https://www.mysite dot com/$1 [R=301,L]
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Note first five lines are comments (they used for https and I disable that). Now I need update second part of htaccess code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't fix this without installing a proper SSL certificate.

The client connects to the server using SSL (because https://), and it does not proceed with anything sent by the webserver until after that handshake is completed. And so the client does not complete the handshake, because it sees that the certificate is invalid.